# GKE node from new node pool gets 403 on artifact registry image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a gke cluster with two node pools.

By mistake I deleted an image from Artifact Registry and did a rollout that end with some pods in `ImagePullBackOff` (403 Forbidden). After creating back the image (via a Cloud Build build from git tag) I created a third node pool and deleted one of the pool that I had. Now the situation is that the pods in the old pool are able to download the image and the pods into the newly created pool are in `ImagePullBackOff` again (403 Forbidden again).

I have tried to create a forth pool but the situation is the same. I have a second gke cluster and the issue described is absent.

Have you got any idea why newly created pools into the first gke cluster are unable to download the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by waiting (a lot...) and creating back a new pool.